# Regarding batch jobs in APEX

Tags: apex

When we create accounts using scheduled jobs and run a batch job only few of them are flowing and remaining are  failing. what might be the cause where I need to check?

Comment: you can check in apex jobs. It will show the status details

Comment: If you run the developer console whilst the batches are being processed you may see some exceptions thrown - or pointers to the issue.

Comment: I need to have batchable interface and schedulable interface to create accounts right?

Comment: @Richard, do I need to run the batchable interface in DEveloper console?

Comment: As this is very new concept to me please help me out

Comment: Start the dev console and check the logs are being recorded. Carry out the process you are currently using to create the Accounts and you should see activity. Or look in the monitoring admin logs.